# Launch Reporting Services Reports from .Net Code

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting-services, integration

What is the best way to launch reporting services reports from .Net code?  One method would be to dynamically build a URL and launch a browser. Something like this:

```
http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReport+Directory%2fReport%20Name&FirstParameter=1,2,3&SecondParameter=8/30/2009&rs%3aCommand=Render
```

I don't like how it creates a dependency on the specific URL--especially report parameters which are very likely to change. Is there a better way?

The reports I want to link to are in several reporting services projects hosted on one (eventually two) servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Integrating Reporting Services into Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx) give you the 3 options

As well as URL Access, you can either call the RS web service using SOAP or use the ReportViewer control.

Either way, you have a dependency on a URL (but that's how web services work), unless you use the ReportViewer control in [local processing mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use System.Diagnostics.Process start the above url?